# Checking empty cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

In python `str(None)` is `"None"`. But when reading a cell with openpyxl we get a None instead of an empty string. So when casting the empty cell we end up with an object with a different bool value.

This causes errors if a value would need to be checked if it's empty.

If it's going to be written out, it won't be actually show nothing but None.

I was not explicitly calling str but when I was construction a formula I was doing it so with f-string like
`f"=COUNTIF(A1:A100, {cell_contents})"`. Where `cell_contents` were `None`. Currently I fixed this problem with checking if the value I read is `False`,and then assign empty string.
`cell_contents = i or ""` I'm expecting cell values to be a name as I'm trying to count the occurrences of these names.
What would be a better implementation for this?

Comment: How would you distinguish `print(None)` from `print("")`? To me, these are quite different. None indicates an optional value; an empty string indicates e.g. that a user didn't fill in anything in an input.

Comment: "First of all they have the same bool value.": you mean for the `str()` represenation? That is not relevant here: you would compare the actual values, None and "". Not their string representations.

Comment: "Why" questions on language design [generally aren't on-topic here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394): they aren't about _a specific problem you actually face_. Knowing why Guido made a particular decision more than 25 years ago can't change how you write code today, and informing the _practice_ of software development is what Stack Overflow is all about. To have a clearly on-topic question, edit it to take out the "why"/historical parts and focus narrowly on the practical problem you're trying to address in the present.

Comment: The second part of the question looks like XY problem. What are actually doing and what you want to achieve?

Comment: So I think your actual question is the last two paragraphs? And the rest is rather irrelevant?

Comment: What would be a better title for my question, 'checking empty cells using openpyxl'? I wasn't sure if I'm using the tools python gives me correctly, that's why I wanted to ask it on a more fundamental level.

Comment: So the problem appears to be how Excel represents missing values versus an empty cell. These would also be a problem when saving to e.g. a CSV file. But that's not really a Python problem: it's an (export) problem more on the Excel/CSV side of things. You could work around it by having a special indicator for thoses empty cells (that are not an empty string). Then upon reading (with openpyxl or Pandas), turn the cells with those values into "missing" (None, or perhaps something else).

Comment: Yes, "checking empty cells using openpyxl" would be a better title. Withdrawing my close vote in anticipation of an edit to that effect.

Comment: Do note that `None` does have it's own `__str__`. You're getting `object.__str__`, which delegates to the objects `__repr__`. As a rule, `repr`s try to return strings that are (or at least approximate) valid literals for the represented object. This is true for most (all?) builtin types

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited my question to be more specific. I think the comments look a bit out of the place now but I don't know how could I have edited it better.

Comment: "Currently I fixed this problem with checking if the value I read is False,and then assign empty string. cell_contents = i or "" What would be a better implementation for this?" Answering this requires a clearer understanding of the problem. Where did "cell_contents" come from? What values and types can it have? In each case, what should the resulting string be, and **why**? What will be done with the resulting formatted string?